# Calulate density with transformation

Tags: probability

Give the density $ f_{X}(x)=\frac {x^2} {9} $ with $0 < x < 3$

I should calculate with transformation the density of $Y=X^3$.

Is my calculation correct?

$f_{Y}(y)=f_{X}(g^{-1}(y))\mid\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)\mid = \frac {(y^{\frac{2}{3}})^2} {9}*\frac{1}{3y^2} =\frac{1}{27}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f_Y$ is supported on $I=[0,27]$ and for every $t\in I$ we have:
$$ \mathbb{P}[Y\leq t] = \mathbb{P}[X\leq t^{1/3}] = \int_{0}^{t^{1/3}}\frac{x^2}{9}\,dx = \frac{t}{27} $$
hence $Y$ is uniformly distributed and your answer is correct.